# Find multiple solutions using pyomo and gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi, pyomo

I am solving a MILP using Gurobi and Pyomo. I would like to obtain as many *optimal* solutions as possible. Here is what I have so far:

```
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
n_of_s = 10
opt.set_instance(model)
opt.set_gurobi_param('PoolSolutions', n_of_s)
opt.set_gurobi_param('PoolSearchMode', 2)
opt.solve(model, tee=True)
opt.set_gurobi_param('SolutionNumber',2) 
model.pprint()
```

At some point Gurobi displays `Solution count 3: 5000 5000 5000`. However, when trying to access the value of optimal variables, I can only access one solution.

I have tried using the `Xn` attribute, but Gurobi states `AttributeError: '_GeneralVarData' object has no attribute 'Xn'`.

Comment: Do you mean local optimum? Most of the time, there is only one global optimum. I remember seeing a way to add a hash function constraint somewhere.

Comment: No I mean global. It's a milp

Comment: May be constraint the solution to be not equal to existing solutions? Stop when the objective function's value at the optimum changes.

Comment: I changed three gurobi parameters and it worked for me. PoolSolutions : how many MIP solutions to be stored (set it to 500)? PoolGap: Limit the search space by setting a gap for the worst possible solution that will be accepted (0.8 for 80% worst solution). PoolSearchMode:  Do a systematic search for the k-best solutions (setting it to 2 forces gurobi to find required no. of feasible solutions if they exist).

Comment: After solving the model, check how many solutions were stored by printing `m.SolCount `. Then, you can retrieve those solutions using: `for sol in range(m.SolCount  - 1):  m.setParam(GRB.Param.SolutionNumber, sol+1); var.Xn`

Comment: @PrameshKumar Could you please elaborate your answer? I get a `AttributeError: 'ConcreteModel' object has no attribute 'SolCount'`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. For example, with Pyomo package, the gurobi solver is selected using the following code:

```
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io='python')
opt.options["NonConvex"] = 2
opt.options['MIPGap'] = 0.01
opt.options['SolCount'] = 2

results = opt.solve(model, load_solutions=True, tee=True)
```

The attributes of gurobi solver can be visited by using `opt._solver_model`. For example, you can see the number of solutions by calling its attribute of `'SolCount'` as `opt._solver_model.SolCount`. Similarly, you can access the multiple solutions by using its attribute `Xn` in the same way as using "Gurobi" directly. For example, you can access all the solutions in this way:

```
xs=[]
for s in range(opt._solver_model.SolCount):
   opt._solver_model.params.SolutionNumber = s
   x=opt._solver_model.getAttr("Xn")
   xs.append(x)
```

Similarly, you can access all gurobi solver's attributes. BTW, you can read the code under pyomo package to see how pyomo visits gurobi solver in the directory of `...\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\gurobi_direct.py`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did not see "add more lines". I did edit my first answer before, so I am not sure which one you are seeing. Anyway, it does not make any sense. Ignore it, pls. (it was my first time to post on this forum, so I might have already made some confusion about how to properly use the forum; sorry for that)